# How to more easily debug ASP.NET applications in Visual Studio when there are multiple simultaneous requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

When interactively debugging ASP.NET (or ASP.NET MVC) applications in Visual Studio (regardless of whether it be local or remote debugging) the debugging process often gets complex because the web application may receive multiple requests while I'm trying to step through code.  As a result the currently executing line jumps all over the place.

Is there a way of either limiting the number of requests to 1, or, somehow isolating the debugging of an individual request so I don't jump around between lines of code?

Update: I’ve tried playing with the Threads window but do not see a solution to my problem.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the Threads window under debug?

Comment: @the_lotus Interesting.  Playing now.  I see that I can flag a thread that corresponds to code on a particular breakpoint, but not clear to me how I take that to the next step to be able to isolate (and focus on) a given request.

Comment: Look into making sequence diagrams, this will help you get the overview of your problem. For the rest, thread id and output window.

Comment: @ikwillem Can you please clarify how making sequence diagrams helps here?  I know the flow of my app, I just want to avoid extraneous requests when I am debugging a given request.

Comment: Actually making the diagram will help you understand the flow better step by step, by making it visible. This will make the problem clear as day. I can't write too long comments, so I'll post it as an answer with some samples, give me a minute.

Comment: @ikwillem I'll comment under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As requested my clearification of the Sequence Diagram solution:

A sequence diagram makes your application flow visible. The key is to write it by hand and only include the main flow, so if your class uses 4 functions to execute a certain path, just write down that it went to that class and what it did, no need to make 4 different participants.

To write sequence diagrams I usually use https://www.websequencediagrams.com/ it's a excellent website.

To show you the power of sequence diagrams I made this example:
[image: Webcam sequence diagram example]

What you see here is a simple flow of a application that shows you the image of a webcam. The problem of the application is that webcam frame/bitmap is disposed while painting it to the frontend. With the sequence diagram you can see why.

You can also combine this with your application logging. When you let the processes log all your "sequence diagram"-steps you can backtrace in your logging what happend when.

EDIT:

The solution to this particular problem with the webcam is to use autoresetevents, you basicly suspend the one thread till the other thread gives a go. You can also do this with databases by trying to update something and looking at the result.

Comment: Wow thanks for posting all this.  I appreciate that you took the time.  Honestly though while I love your idea for many scenarios I am not sure it is a fit for my problem because it is not the flow or sequence that presents my challenge but rather simply that as multiple requests come in my debugging location jumps all over and is a big pain.  It is just a waste of time and effort to work through multiple requests.  It would be like retracing your steps to find a piece of lost jewelery, only to randomly be brought back to places you've already looked.

Comment: Ok, well, have you tried removing the break point before you hit F10?

Comment: BTW, If that is the solution, your doing it wrong, I don't know what it is, but it's wrong. I don't want to be mean or something, but whatever is calling that code asynchronously should stop it and make it just 1 call. It's super inefficient, plus a pain to debug.

Comment: How can you possibly make a statement as absolute as "whatever is calling that code asynchronously should stop it" - it's a web controller method!  That's what web controller methods do, they get called simultaneously by different clients.  With respect to removing the breakpoint before I hit F10, I think you are missing my point.  Per my question I simply want to "isolate" debugging of a single request, hopefully by limiting the quantity of requests to 1, but it appears that isn't possible.